# react and redux es2015 modules for use as-is

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Are there react and redux es2015 modules for use as-is--without a build step and not globals?

Something like:

```
// wget 'https....react.js' (and others)
import React from './react.js'
import { render } from './react-dom.js'
import { Provider } from './react-redux.js'
import { createStore } from './react-redux.js'

//.... work ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not ES2015 modules, no.  However, React, Redux, and React-Redux all have UMD builds available (which can be loaded as plain script tags, CommonJS modules, and AMD modules).

Comment: thanks @markerikson yes I'm aware of the older module systems and was looking to use these resources directly, without a build step as part of a modern unbundled development workflow (using js modules). sorry to hear this is the case.

Comment: React itself is not published as ES6 modules, because it has to go through a heavy transformation process for optimization.  The Redux and React-Redux packages do have the ES6 source available as part of our NPM packages, in addition to the UMD builds and the ES5-targeted CommonJS files.  If you have a specific use case that we're not targeting right now for Redux, please file an issue.